# SSL Connect Error in Curl and Php 5.3.3

Tags: php, ssl, curl

My site worked perfectly since 3 years, with below code, now suddenly since 2 days it started giving below error :

SSL Connect error :- in Curl_error

Below is my code :

```
<?php
$this->ssl_cert = "path_to_my_cert.pem";
$session = curl_init($this->server_url);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->request_header);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, rsa_rc4_128_sha);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $this->ssl_cert);
$response = curl_exec($session);

if (curl_errno($session)) {
    $curl_err = curl_error($session);
    return array("CURL_ERR", $curl_err);
} else {
    curl_close($session);
}
?>
```

I have 5 different api's working using the above same code and every thing worked perfectly since 3 years. Suddenly one of my api has started giving the error : SSL Connect error.

After few search on net, if found of few of the solutions and tried adding below code to but all in vein :

```
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
```

My PHP Version : 5.3.3
cURL Information : 7.9.17

Comment: Issue solved. After few debugging tricks using below link : http://blog.techstacks.com/2010/03/3-common-causes-of-unknown-ssl-protocol-errors-with-curl.html, came to know that my CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST value had the issue. Commented it for now and the web services are working perfectly. The proper solution now for me would be finding out the actual new value for the Cipher and bring back the code. Writing back so that it might help some one in future.

Comment: Using [link] http://blog.techstacks.com/2010/03/3-common-causes-of-unknown-ssl-protocol-errors-with-curl.html would help to debug any Curl related issue. Keeping the link might be handy :)